# How to identify 2 consecutive a specific special character?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following string

`@@ test string`

`@ test string @ another test string`

I need the following output:

```
var re = /^([@])\1*$/;
re.test("@@ test string")
> true
re.test("@ test string @ another test string")
> false
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are the conditions?

Comment: Is there a list of special characters  or just `@`?

Comment: Try this - `\W{2}`

Comment: just for `@` @adiga

Comment: Why do you have `^`. Is it supposed to be  only in the beginning of string? If it's anywhere in the string `/@{2}/` should be fine

Comment: or "@@.*"... if you're looking specifically for 2 @

Comment: I just want to understand: Why does the first string is ok, and the second not?

Comment: *There are ingredients. I want a Scallop Sashimi with Meyer Lemon Confit.* That doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/@@/
```

If you want a "special<sup>*</sup> characters" regex:

```
/\W\W/
```

If you want a solution that's easily expandable, use a negated character class approach:

```
/[^\w]{2}/
```

<sup>*</sup><sub>Special is here defined as a non-word character (exact matches may vary from engine to engine)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Why not use just `@@`?

```js
var re = /@@/;
console.log(re.test("@@ test string"));
console.log(re.test("@ test string @ another test string"));
```

Comment: Why do you need the global flag?

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` instead of `*`, add **g** (global), and some other small modifications to your regexp:

```js
var re = /(@)\1+/g;
console.log('re @@', re.test("@@ test string"))
console.log('re @', re.test("@ test string @ another test string"))

var otherRe = /@{2}/g;
console.log('otherRe @@', otherRe.test("@@ test string"))
console.log('otherRe @', otherRe.test("@ test string @ another test string"))

var otherRe2 = /@@/g;
console.log('otherRe2 @@', otherRe2.test("@@ test string"))
console.log('otherRe2 @', otherRe2.test("@ test string @ another test string"))
```

But if you want exactly two **@** s, then you really should use **(@@)** - easiest, most reliable expression for this case.